# How to get query string value on html.exx file?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am new on phoenix, elixir. I am trying to get params[:task_id] on text_field on new.html.exx , something like below rails code.

```
<%= f.text_field :task_id, value: params[:task_id] %>
```

I found below info on iex shell

```
[info] GET /tasks/1/comments/new
[debug] Processing by HelloWorld.CommentController.new/2
Parameters: %{"task_id" => "1"}
```

I tried with IEX.pry and got following result, but i am not able to apply it on text_input value.

```
pry(3)> conn.params["task_id"]
"1"
```

Also tried below code but no luck.

```
<%= text_input f, :task_id, value: @conn.params["task_id"] %>
Got Error: assign @conn not available in eex template.
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you are inserting this into a database, you can use Ecto's changesets which make this very easy for you.

Comment: @JustinWood:  changeset = Comment.changeset(%Comment{}, comment_params)
Repo.insert(changeset). Is this what you mean by Ecto's changesets? Sorry for this question. As newbie on this technology, just curious to know if i am going right way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the copy of `params` available in `@conn` (which is available in all templates rendered directly using `Phoenix.Controller.render`).

```
# new.html.eex
<%= @conn.params["task_id"] %>
```

If you want to use `@conn` in a template rendered using `Phoenix.View.render` inside the main template, you need to explicitly pass it to the new template:

```
# new.html.eex
<%= render "form.html", ..., conn: @conn %>
```

You can also just pass in `params`:

```
# new.html.eex
<%= render "form.html", ..., params: @conn.params %>
```

and use `@params`:

```
# form.html.eex
<%= @params["task_id"] %>
```

Comment: I tried that already, i got the error. ArgumentError at GET /tasks/1/comments/new
assign @conn not available in eex template.

Comment: the code is inside form.html.exx within form_for block, and which is rendered inside new.html.eex

Comment: I tried it inside new.html.eex and it worked, thanks. But i want to use inside text_field or hidden_field within form_for section

Answer (score 2):

Based on comments, you appear to be using Ecto and Changesets.

Given some schema

```
schema "foo" do
  field :name, :string
  field :age, :integer
end
```

You can have something like this in your controller

```
def new(conn, _params) do
  changeset = Foo.changeset(%Foo{})
  render conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset
end
```

Which will allow you to have something like this in your html view file.

```
= form_for @changeset, foo_path(@conn, :create), [as: :foo], fn f ->
  = text_input f, :name
  = number_input f, :age
  = submit "Submit"
- end
```

Then back to your controller for the create method

```
def create(conn, %{"foo" => foo_params}) do
  foo = Foo.changeset(%Foo{}, foo_params)

  case Repo.insert(foo) do
    {:ok, foo} -> redirect conn, to: foo_path(:show, foo)
    {:error, changeset} -> render conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset
  end
end
```

Depending on your needs, the logic may be different, but you can take advantage of the changeset to fill the form in for you.

Comment: Thanks Justin, i understand the usage of changeset. +1 for your answer too.

Comment: one question: task = Repo.get(Task, 1), comments = Repo.preload(task, :comments) works. But task.comments says task: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :task is not loaded> Thanks.

Comment: Elixir has immutable data structures. Meaning when you called `Repo.preload/2` it does not put the comments data into the original `task` variable. Your `comments` variable now has the original `Task` with the associated `comments` information.

Comment: Yes you are correct, comments variable holds both original tasks and associated comments. Thanks for your valuable time.